# Transformations of Functions - What are the Order of Operations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to confirm the order of operations when it comes to transformations.

For example: 1/2 square root (x+4) -3

Is the order of operations:

Evaluate expression within the parentheses 1st (or whatever is under the square root sign, not sure if square roots are equivalent to parentheses); secondly, exponents; 3rd, multiplication / division left to right (whichever one comes first); and lastly, Addition and subtraction left to right (which ever one comes first).

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=\tfrac1{2\sqrt{x+4}-3}$?

Comment: No, 3 multiplied by the square root of x+2 (radicand) + 4

Comment: So you mean $3 \sqrt{x+2} + 4$?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

To find $f(x)=3\sqrt{x+2}+4$ for a particular value of $x$, you have to replace $x$ inside the square root, then evaluate the latter. After that, you multiply what you get by 3 and you then add 4.

**Example**: Let's find $f(7)$. We have $f(x)=3\sqrt{x+2}+4$ therefore: $$\begin{align*}
f(7)&=3\sqrt{7+2}+4\\ &=3\sqrt{9}+4\qquad\qquad\color{grey}{\text{we know that: }} \sqrt{9}=3 \\ &=3\cdot 3+4\\ &= 9+4 \\ &=13.
\end{align*}$$

I hope this helps.

Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.